# Qwt QwtScaleEngine

Tags: qt, qwt

I have a QwtPlot. 
This plot is autoscalable but I would like to limit the distention to avoid that my plot be extended only between 46.5 and 47.5. I would for example, that my plot wasn't extented on less of 5 unites.

I know I must use QwtScaleEngine but I don't how ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems, that you have no need to use QwtScaleEngine
try this kind of code:

```
plot=new QwtPlot(parent);
plot->setAxisAutoScale(QwtPlot::yLeft,false);
plot->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft,minYBorder,maxYBorder,0);
```

QwtScaleEngine is better in use for formatting like:

```
class TimeScaleDraw:public QwtScaleDraw{
public:
    TimeScaleDraw(QString fmt):format(fmt){}
    virtual         QwtText label(double v) const{
    return (QDateTime::fromMSecsSinceEpoch(floor(v))).toString(format);    }
private:
    const           QString format;
};
```